# sql - Insert between two rows?

Tags: sql, insert

I wish to know how I can insert a row between the two rows of a table.
I am using MS-SQL and SQL management studio.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: err... SQL rows aren't ordered...

Comment: What do you mean insert "between two rows"? Is it dependent on value of some column in your table?

Comment: I did not know that SQL rows are not ordered. I just thought that the rows are ordered in the way that they show up in the table of Management Studio

Comment: Does that mean I have to specify a new column to order my rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do just a

```
SELECT (columns) FROM dbo.MyTable
```

there is no guaranteed order in the output - it might look like it's ordered, but there's no guarantee for anything.

If you want to **order** by something, you need to explicitly specify that by adding an **ORDER BY** clause to your statement:

```
SELECT (cols) FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY FirstName
```

Therefore, you cannot "insert" a new row between two other rows - it will just show up wherever it belongs, based on the order you've defined

Comment: Also, you can order by any column in the table, in multiple levels, and descending too: `ORDER BY BirthDate DESC, FirstName, Surname`

Comment: @wesley: yes, sure! If you have large tables, it might be a good idea to have an index on columns that you frequently order by - speeds things up

Answer (score 1):

You can order the rows according to the column values in ascending or descending order

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_newsletter ORDER BY newsletter_email ASC
```

here the rows are ordered in ascending order of the column `newsletter_email`

You can use `DESC` for ordering in descending order.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.